# How to reformat an XML file's element attributes?

Tags: xml

I have an XML file with some persons described in it.

This is the current state.

```
<Person
    ID="1"
    Name="John"
    LastName="Williams"
    Address="Main Street 23"/>
<Person
    ID="2"
    FirstName="Peter"
    LastName="Johnson"
    Address="Second Street 12"/>
```

What I would like is this instead.

```
<Person ID="1" FirstName="John" LastName="Williams" Address="Main Street 26"/>
<Person ID="2" FirstName="Peter" LastName="Johnson" Address="Second Street 12"/>
```

Is there an easy way to reformat the XML file?